# How to calculate this integral including the absolute value function and the exponential function？

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to calculate the integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(-\frac{1}{2} (Ax^2+Bx))~\exp(-\frac{1}{2} (Cy^2+Dy))~\exp(Exy)~|Jx + Ky + L|~{\rm d}x{\rm d}y.$$
However, I have no idea about how to deal with this kind of integral including the absolute value function. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can handle the absolute value by breaking the integral into a sum of integrals one over the region where $Jx+Ky+L \geq 0 $ and the other $Jx+Ky+L<0$

Comment: I don't know if you are trying to solve for any generic constants $A,B,C...$ but if they have specific values in your question then I think a substitution $u = ax + by$ and $v = cx + dy$ might be helpful. And of course in addition to the above suggestion.